# How Can I Improve My Pygame Text Function?

Tags: function, text, pygame

I want to improve this text function I use hopefully using a dictionary to store values but I don't know how.

The code:

```py
def text(text, x, y, size, color):
    # the font for the text
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, size)
    # the text itself
    txt = font.render(text, 0, color)
    # draw the text
    screen.blit(txt, (x, y))
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Rob The question looks to be CNIONWAI and so is off-topic on Code Review. Please read Code Review's help center before making more poor recomendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify what font you will use "font_name.ttf"

```
font_type = 'font_name.ttf'

def draw_text(text, color, size, x, y):
    font = pygame.font.Font(font_type, size)
    text = font.render(text, False, color)
    text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(x, y))
    screen.blit(text, text_rect)
```

I hope it will help you, Adam

Comment: Sorry, lol I figured it out.